# Access 2010: Report Prints Three Extra Pages

Tags: ms-access, printing, report, ms-access-2010

In Access 2010, I have a button that launches a macro that prints a report. Button->Macro->Report. The report is only on one page and is 8.1 in width. It will not go to 8.

I have deleted the header and footers and all that is left is the detail portion. It is contained on one page, but it prints 3 extra pages. I have been scouring Google and messing with the report properties, but nothing has stopped it from printing 3 extra pages.

The page margins are set at .25" all around.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say you "deleted" the header and footers.  Under design view, set the "visible" property for the headers/footers to "no" to see what is causing the issue.  Often it is the footers that cause weird page breaks.  If you find out that a footer is the culprit, you could make an additional group level with only a footer and copy all the data in either the page or report footer into that other footer.  I usually have it group on expression "=1" and set the report footer "visible" to "no".